# InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token Twitch

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitch

Hey I am at a standstill. I am not sure whats going on but I am unable to obtain my access token. I am trying to use a Passport strategy for twitch authentication. The error I am running into is InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain an access token at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError. What am I doing wrong?

Passport Strategy

```
passport.use(
    new TwitchStrategy({
        clientID: keys.twitchClientID,
        clientSecrect: keys.twitchClientSecrect,
        // callbackURL:'/auth/twitch/callback',
        callbackURL:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/twitch/callback',
        scope: "user:read:email analytics:read:games",
        proxy: true
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        console.log(accessToken);
        console.log(profile);
    })
)
```

Auth Router

```
router.get("/twitch", passport.authenticate("twitch.js"));

router.get(
  "/twitch/callback",
  passport.authenticate("twitch.js", { failureRedirect: "/" }),
  (req, res) => {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect("/");
  }
);
```

NPM Package

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-twitch.js
```

Redirect URL from Authentication

```
http://localhost:5000/auth/twitch/callback?code=xqp1au3zqigezj8dzeslcvih8mqn6x&scope=user%3Aread%3Aemail+analytics%3Aread%3Agames
```

Comment: sorry but is this an access token for your twitch account? or are you creating access tokens for your users through this token?

Comment: your access token from twitch is available in the response header from the callback... so in order to get that you look for it there. Test it in postman

Comment: This is a user token so this redirect url I linked comes from twitch I believe once I make it through the login with twitch.

Comment: ok it seems to work for me (minus the redirect url) but here is your issue, change this line passport.authenticate("twitch")); and this line passport.authenticate("twitch"));

Comment: actually it didnt work. The issue is you are trying to authenticate and get a USER TOKEN using app credentials...

Comment: So whats the problem doing it that way? I am not following and thanks for the reply.

Comment: Let me work on it for a bit. But basically first you need to get authorization for your app using OAuth 2 and pass that as an access token and then use the passport strategy you have.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks, if it helps here a reference, its pretty foreign to me tho :D.https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication

Comment: After reading the documentation, I drilled down your problem. The issue is that you are authenticating your user through an implicit grant flow. The authorization token is not passed back to the server on purpose. In other words you need to implement your passport strategy in the client side not server side. If you are using angular passport has a module for that. Otherwise if you are rendering through node you can set up an html page that receives the redirect and then calls the second passport.authenticate.

Comment: Other wise you can do this from your server using an authorization token. You can get it using postman or set up a request.get with OAuth library. Will be posting the answer in a couple of hours as I am afk rn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you are a working copy for your set up:

firstly make sure to enable the strategy with sessions using app.use(passport.initialize());
and to include the serialize and deserialize, this is where your code will get the authtoken from the server.

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Twitch = require('./model');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require('passport');
const twitchStrategy = require("passport-twitch").Strategy;


mongoose
  .connect(
    "<mongourl>"
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connected to database!");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("connection failed");
  });

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PUT"
  );

  next();
});
app.use(passport.initialize());

passport.use(new twitchStrategy({
  clientID: "<clientid>",
  clientSecret: "<clientsecret>",
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/twitch/callback",
  scope: "user_read"
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
 
  twitch.save({ twitchId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
    console.log(user);
    return done(err, user);
  });
}

));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log(user);
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send(`<html><head></head><body>Here</body></html>`);
});


app.get("/auth/twitch", passport.authenticate("twitch"));


 app.get("/auth/twitch/callback" ,passport.authenticate("twitch"), function(req, res) {

 
  res.redirect("/");
});





module.exports = app;
```

without sessions

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require('passport');
const twitchStrategy = require("passport-twitch").Strategy;
const axios = require('axios');
const twitchAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers:{
    "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "bearer TOKEN" 
  }
});


mongoose
  .connect(
    ""
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connected to database!");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("connection failed");
  });

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PUT"
  );

  next();
});
app.use(passport.initialize());

passport.use(new twitchStrategy({
  clientID: "",
  clientSecret: "",
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/twitch/callback",
  scope: "user_read"
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

  twitch.save({ twitchId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
    return done(err, user);
  });
}

));


app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send(`<html><head></head><body>Here</body></html>`);
});


app.get("/auth/twitch", passport.authenticate("twitch",{session: false}));


 app.get("/auth/twitch/callback", function(req, res) {
   twitchAxios.get('/').then(console.log)


 
  res.redirect("/");
});





module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, I still am failing to obtain an access token though :/.

Comment: will update a post without need for for sessions later

Comment: Thank you it is much appreciated!

Comment: Updated code without sessions, you can add a JwT strategy to protect the tokens as well. Please upvote if this worked for you thanks